# Spring Data Rest - How to have an association relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two classes, `Role` and `Permission` with a ManyToMany relationship between them. My problem is that each relationship has some extra data that comes with it therefore I believe I need to create an intermediary class to store these extra data, so that is the `RolePermission` class.

This is basically what I have, the `parameter` and `domain` are the extra data that are required for each relationship.

[image]

Here is the code I have right now for my classes.

Role.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sec_Role")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String name;

    // This is another relationship which is working just fine (because there are no intermediary data needed.
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    private Set<Group> groups;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "role")
    private List<RolePermission> permissions = new ArrayList<RolePermission>(0);

    ...Standard getters and setters and constructor
```

Permission.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sec_Permission")
public class Permission {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "permission")
    private List<RolePermission> roles = new ArrayList<RolePermission>(0);

    ...Standard getters and setters and constructor
```

RolePermission.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sec_Role_Permission")
@DynamicUpdate
public class RolePermission {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private int domain;
    private String parameter;
    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private int role_id;
    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private int permission_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", nullable = false)
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", nullable = false)
    private Permission permission;

    ...Standard getters and setters and constructor
```

Every class has a standard Repository like so

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "roles")
public interface RoleRepository extends CrudRepository<Role, Integer> {

}
```

Now this code works fine for reading data and relationships, my problem is that I cannot figure out what I am suppose to do or what end point to call to add/modify/delete a relationship between `Role` and `Permission`.

Currently if I call `/roles/11/permissions` I will get this back:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "rolePermissions": []
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8887/api/v1/roles/11/permissions"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add a permission to this role?

I tried executing a POST request to `/roles/11/permissions` with the following JSON body and I got a `204` No Content response. This basically means success but then when I do a GET request to `/roles/11/permissions` I do not see permission with ID `1` there so it did not work.

```
{
  "domain": 0,
  "parameter": "Some param",
  "role_id": 11,
  "permission_id": 1
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to add it inside the POST method?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Sorry I didn't understand your question. I tried to add by using both POST and PUT methods but none of them worked. It's hard because i'm going off of just guessing what I should do. I'm hoping someone here has done a similar setup and could help me with how I am suppose to call the API to add/modify or delete relationships.

Comment: Thats why my question.. what is happening inside POST for example. What happens before you trigger save on the repository

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I edited my question to show you what I tried with the POST request that I sent.

Comment: Ok good. Now what happens inside the Controller method?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski There are no controllers, so far Spring Data has been automatically handling everything. I have some other classes not mentioned here and they are all working fine for all CRUD operations without the need of a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Since your mapping is itself an `Entity` you can model your API based on the Resource ( in this case `RolePermission`). Basically when you would want to provide an API to add `rolepermission`

Some thing like

```
http://localhost:8887/api/v1/rolepermission

POST 

{
 "roleid":"xxxxx"
"permissionid":"xxxxxx"
"parameterid":"xxxxxx"
"domain":"xxxxx"

}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I get the following error with a 409 status message: `could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`